# Почему GET запрос может не передавать данные?

Tags: php

Например у меня есть ссылка:

```
<a href="list_instructors.php?show_archive=1"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            Show Archived Instructors</button></a>
```

и условие:

```
if (isset($_GET['show_archive']) && $_GET['show_archive'] == 1)
    $status_filter = "STATUS=0";
else
    $status_filter = "STATUS=1 OR STATUS=2";
```

Но когда после перехода я проверяю содержимое `$_GET`, то ключа `show_archive` нет

Comment: что это значит? вы заходите куда по ссылке? где хотите чтобы оно было? php выполняется каждый раз при вызове, так сказать с чистого листа. если нужно что то хранить, можете использовать куки или сессии

Comment: А проверяете `$_GET` в файле `list_instructors.php`? Не напутали с именем?